# Unable to target materialize select dropdown list item

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

**My HTML**

```
<div id="address-book" class="col s6">
 <label>ADDRESS BOOK</label>
 <select class="clean-input">
  <option disabled selected>Choose Address</option>
  <option>Saved address 1</option>
  <option>Saved address 2</option>
  <option>Saved address 3</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

**What `materialize` generates:**

```
<div id="address-book" class="col s6">
  <label>ADDRESS BOOK</label>
  <div class="select-wrapper clean-input initialized"><span class="caret">▼</span><input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-77f55358-fb61-17c0-08b1-78d72bff710c" value="Choose Address">
    <ul id="select-options-77f55358-fb61-17c0-08b1-78d72bff710c" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
      <li class="disabled "><span>Choose Address</span></li>
      <li class=""><span>Saved address 1</span></li>
      <li class=""><span>Saved address 2</span></li>
      <li class=""><span>Saved address 3</span></li>
    </ul>
    <select class="clean-input initialized">
    <option disabled="" selected="">Choose Address</option>
    <option>Saved address 1</option>
    <option>Saved address 2</option>
    <option>Saved address 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My attempt to target the dropdown list item:**

```
$('#address-book div ul li').on('click', function(){
 $(alert('yes'));
});
```

I have tried multiple different ways to drilldown into the list item, but they do not work. I created the exact drilldown as a test and the alert worked.

Answer (score 1):

you need use `.dropdown-button`  class instead of `.select-dropdown`

see more info about materalize dropdowns [here](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html)

```js
$('.dropdown-button').on('click', function() {
  console.log('yes');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.js"></script>
<div class="select-wrapper clean-input initialized"><span class="caret">▼</span>
  <input type="text" href="#" class="dropdown-button btn" data-activates="drop" readonly="true" value="Choose Address" />
  <ul id="drop" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
    <li class="disabled "><span>Choose Address</span>
    </li>
    <li class=""><span>Saved address 1</span>
    </li>
    <li class=""><span>Saved address 2</span>
    </li>
    <li class=""><span>Saved address 3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the list items to be the target, not the UL. Since materialize generates this, I can't hard code classes onto the List Items.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with `select` being turned into a `ul` by Materialize, you can add the class `class="browse-default"` to the `select` tag and you get a`select` without the `ul`.

Here's a snippet that targets the options and print the value of the selected option int the console :

```js
$('select').on('change',function(){
  console.log($('select').find(":selected").text());
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.js"></script>
<label>Browser Select</label>
  <select class="browser-default">
    <option disabled selected>Choose Address</option>
      <option>Saved address 1</option>
      <option>Saved address 2</option>
      <option>Saved address 3</option>
  </select>
```